# Error in linking libmpi.so

Tags: linux, arch-linux, links

I installed openmpi on my machine and I used to run some code, but after updating openmpi, I could not link shared library `libmpi.so` to my code. the error I got is :

> error while loading shared libraries: libmpi.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

but in dir `/usr/lib/openmpi` I have `libmpi.so.40` not `libmpi.so.12`.

**EDIT:** when I run command `ldconfig -p | grep libmpi`, I see:

```
libmpi_usempif08.so.40 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/openmpi/libmpi_usempif08.so.40
    libmpi_usempif08.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/openmpi/libmpi_usempif08.so
    libmpi_usempi_ignore_tkr.so.40 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/openmpi/libmpi_usempi_ignore_tkr.so.40
    libmpi_usempi_ignore_tkr.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/openmpi/libmpi_usempi_ignore_tkr.so
    libmpi_mpifh.so.40 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/openmpi/libmpi_mpifh.so.40
    libmpi_mpifh.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/openmpi/libmpi_mpifh.so
    libmpi_cxx.so.40 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/openmpi/libmpi_cxx.so.40
    libmpi_cxx.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/openmpi/libmpi_cxx.so
    libmpi.so.40 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/openmpi/libmpi.so.40
    libmpi.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/openmpi/libmpi.so
```

which seems OS knows where to look for `libmpi.so`.

Comment: Did you compile the code on the same system, after OpenMPI installation, or on a different system?

Comment: @grawity yes, I compiled the code in the same system.

Comment: Was that before or after the update?

Comment: @grawity I compiled the code before updating and it worked, but when I updated and then compile the code on the same machine, it did not.

Comment: Can you try again with a _clean_ recompile? That is, remove all leftover `.o` files and such. Do you use `-lmpi` when compiling? If so, what does `ld -o/dev/null -lmpi -t` print out?

Comment: @grawity when I used command `ld -o/dev/null -lmpi -t` what I got is `ld: cannot find -lmpi`. I use flag `-lm` when I compile the code.